# Angular firebase fetching single item has race conditions

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-promise, angularjs-1.6

I'm using angular and firebase together and I have a products array which i'm storing in my rootscope, though it takes time to load the items.

My issues is that when I go to this page for example directly:
http://localhost/product/greyish-sports-shoes

If I go to the home page, the products load after 2 seconds.. and then only if I click on the product link it takes me to it, and it'll work because products have already been loaded.

It goes to the shoeService which contains the products array, but the items are still not loaded, so it cannot find the product by its slug.

That's the code I use in my run method.

```
   var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('products');

    $rootScope.shopProds = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

My shoeService factory:

```
 function shoeFactory($rootScope) {
    this.service = {};

    this.service.store = new Store($rootScope.shopProds);
    this.service.cart = new Cart();

    return this.service;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to realize that the `$firebaseArray` service returns an array that is initially empty. The array is populated asynchronously *after* the data is returned from the server.

Use the promise returned by the `$loaded` method attached to the array:

```
function shoeFactory($rootScope) {
    this.service = {};

    this.service.storePromise = $rootScope.shopProds.$loaded()
      .then ( (shopProds) => {
         return new Store(shopProds);
    });                   

    this.service.cartPromise = this.service.storePromise
      .then ( () => {
        return new Cart();
    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR in shoeFactory");
        throw error;
    }); 

    return this.service;
}
```

To avoid race conditions, the code needs to use promises to chain operations.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way in angular 1 to know if ui state has not been loaded yet? I know it can be done under run method with stateChangeFinished.

Comment: That needs a new question explaining the context, the use case, and an example showing what you have tried so far.